# Is the disc the only subset of R^2 with this property?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry

I don't know if this question has been solved somewhere, but here it goes: Suppose $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is an open subset, such that there exist infinitely many homeomorphisms that restricted to this set give self-maps that are homeomorphisms(i.e there exist a set $\Lambda$ such that $\{T_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in \Lambda }$ are homeomorphisms of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the usual topology, and $T_{\alpha}|_{A}:A\rightarrow A$ is also a homeomorphism, where $|\Lambda| \not < \infty$). Does it mean $A$ is an open disc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many such open sets, here are some silly examples: Take all points that do not have integer x-coordinate, and take horizontal translations by integers (or vertical translates) as homomorphisms.

Or take an open annulus and rotations around its center.

But even a disjoint union of two disks is a counterexample, just stretch a part of the plane where the discs don't lie.

Some more reflection shows that every open set has this property. If it is nonempty, just imagine some deformation of a disk in the interior that preserves the boundary of the disk.

Answer (score 2):

Any open set verifies this property, you can work with two disks $D_1 \subsetneq D_2 \subset A$ included in and make homeomorphisms that preserve $A\setminus D_2$ and rotate  $D_1$ by an angle theta (just fill the gap with lines from the small disk to the big one.

An maybe add the constraint $(T_\lambda)_{|A}$ are all different, because you could do anything elsewhere. This property can be interesting to study on any borelian $A$ though, e.g. for finite sets it does not work since $\mathfrak{S}_n$ is finite.